# How can DB hold a string more than 2 characters if its size 1 byte/8 bits

Tags: string, assembly

I'm learning x86 assembly language and I've got a question to ask how can `db` (data type) can hold a string with more than 2 characters if it's size is only 1 byte or 8 bits?

That means 8 bits can hold 8 binary values like if put `'hello world$'` and its binary value is greater than 8 bits as per calculating all characters or this may possible cause it takes `'hello world$'` as a character and then change it to binary, but i don't know.

If someone tells me how this may be possible, with how it gonna hold it should be good.

Comment: One character of ASCII (or UTF-8 codepoints below U+0080) typically takes up one octet (8-bit byte). If you specify a quoted string to `db` it will act as if you specified multiple `db` directives, each with one octet corresponding to the quoted string's contents.

Comment: I removed the [tag:.net-assembly] tag because ".NET-assembly" has nothing to do with assembly language.

Answer (score 8):

> how db can hold ...

Simple answer:

It can't.

More complex answer:

The statements `db`, `dw` and `dd` (in other assemblers these are called `.byte`, `.word` or similar) mean that **each** element specified is stored in one, two or four bytes of memory.

Example:

`db 1,2,3` means: Store the values 1, 2 and 3; **each** of the three numbers is stored as 8-bit value.

However, `dd 1,2,3` means: Store the values 1, 2 and 3; **each** of the three numbers is stored as 32-bit value (so the entire line of code requires 12 bytes of memory).

I don't know about the exact syntax of the assembler you are using, but something like `db "Hello"` actually means `db "H", "e", "l", "l", "o"`: Each of the 5 elements (`"H"`, `"e"`, `"l"`, `"l"` and `"o"`) is stored in one byte in the memory - so the entire line requires 5 bytes of memory.