# How can 1 byte hold more than one value?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm making a simple assembly program, and I don't understand how, after reserving only 1 byte for a variable `boxresult resb 1d`, a "yes" or "no" can be stored in it, wouldn't I need at least 3 bytes ("no"+terminator) for it?

I've recently searched about it, and it doesn't seem to make sense to me, since: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322270/how-can-db-hold-a-string-more-than-2-characters-if-its-size-1-byte-8-bits) says that by creating a initialized variable "db" it would reserve a byte for each char (which I understand), but in [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860003/how-many-bytes-do-resb-resw-resd-resq-allocate-in-nasm), creating a uninitialized variable how I did would only reserve 1 byte, which wouldn't be able to store more than 1 value (char), but it does.
Here's my code:

```
;https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api
;nasm -fwin32 main2.asm &&gcc main2.obj &&a.exe
;direct version

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE EQU -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE EQU -10
IDYES EQU 6
IDNO EQU 7

extern _MessageBoxA@16 ;4 parameters, each parameter occupies 4 bytes
extern _GetStdHandle@4 ; 1 parameter to identify output port
extern _WriteFile@20 ;5 parameters
extern _ExitProcess@4 ; 1 parameter for exit code

global _main

section .data ;initialized variables
    boxstring db "Choose", 0h ;ends with null
    yes db "yes", 0h
    no db "no", 0h

section .bss ;uninitialized variables
    StandardOutputHandler resd 1d ; 1 uninitialized double variable
    StandardInputHandler resd 1d
    written resd 1d
    boxresult resb 1d

section .text
    _main: ;function start
        ;all values indicated by the API (as far as I've seen) are in hexadecimal, in assembly, just need to declare the type at the end of the number, for example h for hexadecimal, d for decimal, etc.
        ;0 = null
        ;add values for combinations, example: 34h: 4=yesno+30=warning. That is, yes and no and warning icon
        push 44h
        push 0h
        push boxstring
        push 0h
        call _MessageBoxA@16
        cmp eax, IDYES
        jne else
        mov eax, [yes]
        jmp endif
        else:
            mov eax, [no]
        endif:
        mov [boxresult], eax
        push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ;output initialization
        call _GetStdHandle@4
        mov dword [StandardOutputHandler], eax
        push 0h
        push 0h
        push 3d
        push boxresult
        push dword [StandardOutputHandler]
        call _WriteFile@20

        push 0h
        call _ExitProcess@4
```

Comment: A byte is 8 bit, so shouldn't you be able to store 8 yes/no values in it?

Comment: You're overwriting memory after that byte.

Comment: On a modern OS in practice your data section will be rounded up to the page size (4 KiB) so if you overflow a variable at the very end of this section you will access bytes not allocated to any variable. If you had another variable after `boxresult` you would be able to detect that the overflow corrupts the data held in that other variable.

Comment: One byte is 8 bits, so can store any one of 2^8=256 different values.  Usually a character takes a whole byte, and a multibyte string takes more.

Comment: Data memory is mutable, so can hold different values at different times.

Comment: @ecm: You data+BSS (data *segment* in ELF terms, but this is Windows) will effectively end at a 4K boundary, but the actual `.data` section might end as few as 0 bytes from the start of `.bss`. (*[How do 3 random bytes make the code 10 times faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77834973)*). So it's important here that the past-the-end write is at the end of `.bss`, with only a past-the-end read from `.data`.  (Of 4 bytes where `db "no", 0` is only 3).

Comment: Typically you'd use a pointer variable, like `mov dword [boxresult], yes` and `push dword [boxresult]`, unless you're specifically optimizing for short strings.  And if you were, you could have done `mov dword [boxresult], "yes"` or `mov dword [boxresult], "no"` with immediate stores instead of loading from `.data` (or `.rdata` where compilers put read-only strings on Windows.)  Or push that string data on the stack (which will already be hot in cache) and lea/push.

Comment: Or you could just decode the IDYES or not result and `push yes` or `push no` while building the stack args for the next call, and `call _GetStdHandle@4` in the middle of constructing args for a later call, after you'd already consumed the EAX result from MessageBoxA.  So you never need any extra memory storage to hold something based on the messagebox result, just registers.  Or call GetStdHandle much *earlier*, since you're saving its result to a variable as well.

Comment: @PeterCordes, First of all, I want to thank you for your tips and help, and want to say that I'm really just experimenting with the syntax and the behaviors, I tried some things you said earlier without knowing really what I was doing, and now I know, I keep changing this code for "uneccessary" purposes just to see what comes out, and what is possible, in this version i just wanted to know how passing variable values worked with single registers, like `al` can just store 1 char as it's a byte register, or `ax` is 2 bytes, etc

Comment: * just to see what comes out* - I hope you're doing that with a debugger to single-step and look at registers and memory change, to see what different instructions do.  Just looking at the I/O done by running the program doesn't distinguish between working "by accident".

Comment: I see, to be honest, I started learning it by my own and was not doing it with a debugger, doing (what I thought was) simple tests, I'm only used to higher level languages and I'm understanding what the basically "lowest" level language is capable of, and that I will need to be a lot more careful from now on, I am already looking into proper instructions on compiling/running assembly programs, and honestly this just makes me more excited to learn it. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One byte can indeed only hold one byte. If you try to store more than one byte at the given address, by treating that address as the begin of a string, you'll overwrite memory that was not reserved.

Assembly is even less forgiving of errors than C. If you reserve one byte and use two, that is your problem.